# Prolog - Generate Unique Symbol

Tags: prolog, unique, symbols

In Prolog, I am aware of the `gensym` predicate:

```
gensym(g, X).
X = g1.
gensym(g, X).
X = g2.
gensym(g, X).
X = g3.
```

But the docs specifically say:
"Note that this is no guarantee that the atom is unique in the system."

I am looking for a predicate to do that exactly, so that if I am gensymming a new symbol, it will not match one previously used in the same program.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with those atoms? What operations do you envision? Only testing for equality, or something completely different? :)

Comment: [Relevant comment](http://osdir.com/ml/ai.prolog.swi/2004-05/msg00031.html), possibly?

Comment: Describe a use case, as requested by @repeat. It is very probable that you don't need an atom that is "unique in the system", but rather an identifier that is unique within a certain limited scope, for example all clauses of a predicate? As long as you don't use global variables `gensym/2` should definitely be good enough, and even then, as long as you don't do some wild meta-interpreter stuff, it should still be good enough.

Comment: @Boris. How about simply taking a *fresh* variable instead of gensym and testing for equality using `(==)/2`? That does not give you readable names, but the uniqueness guarantee holds. (as long as two or more of these variables are not aliased by unification.)

Comment: @repeat I guess that the rationale behind using atoms is that such "unique keys" are normally used for some kind of look-up, and Prolog systems are optimized for using atoms in this manner.  I'm sure your suggestion has its uses, too.

Comment: @Boris. I think I get your point. OTOH, if "a pointer" is all you need, a attributed variable should do.